# TemplateSyntaxError when accessing default django-allauth login and registration pages

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

I've just installed django-allauth with pip in my django course project. I am getting an error in browser when I try to access either "http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/" or "http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/signup/" :

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /account/login/
Invalid block tag on line 17: 'trans', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/
Django Version: 4.1.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 17: 'trans', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: C:\FSSD Projects\Play2LearnFinal\Play2LearnFinal\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 558, in invalid_block_tag
Raised during:  allauth.account.views.LoginView
Python Executable:  C:\FSSD Projects\Play2LearnFinal\Play2LearnFinal\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\FSSD Projects\\Play2LearnFinal\\Play2LearnFinal',
 'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python311',
 'C:\\FSSD Projects\\Play2LearnFinal\\Play2LearnFinal\\.venv',
 'C:\\FSSD '
 'Projects\\Play2LearnFinal\\Play2LearnFinal\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 17 Mar 2023 13:38:15 -0500
```

Relevant versions I'm running:
Python 3.11.0
Django==4.1.7
django-allauth==0.53.0

I have not modified any of the auth files; only the base settings.py with standard configuration that worked in previous course projects.
Deleting the line did not work.
I tried adding 'django.template.context_processors.i18n' to settings.py TEMPLATES, I also tried adding 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' to MIDDLEWARE. No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an old version of Django:

```
pipenv install django==3.1.0

pipenv install django-allauth==0.43.0
```

For more: [LearnDjango — Django-allauth Tutorial](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-allauth-tutorial).